# Cron Script to run every 5 minutes

Tags: scripts, cron

How would you use a cron deamon to execute a scheduled command such as gathering memory usage and adding that information to a file called /tmp/memory.usage, but only runs on Monday through Thursday every five minutes?  I need to show the date and time before each new entry within the file.  Please assist.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions and help!

Answer (score 11):

- `crontab -e`
- add at the end `*/5 * * * 1-4 /path/to/script &`
- save and exit
- the script is

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "$(date)" >> /tmp/memory.usage
  echo "$(free)" >> /tmp/memory.usage
  echo ""
  ```

see [`man 5 crontab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/crontab.5)  for details. Or, an all-in-one cron line:

```
*/5 * * * 1-4 (echo $(date) && echo $(free) && echo "") >> /tmp/memory.usage
```

Answer (score 2):

`*/5 * * * * /path/to/script`

Make the script executable before that. And make it accessible only for root if the script need elevated privileges.

You can follow the link for more examples 
[Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Comment: This answer runs the job every day of the week and OP asked for Monday through Thursday.